# The Ubuntu partition on my hard disk is not detected on Windows. What to do?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I had a laptop with windows and ubuntu on it on 2 different partitions. Then the laptop stopped working due to issues not related to this question.

I took out the hard drive and put it into an external enclosure to get the data. When I connect it to my other Windows machine, it detects all the other partitions except the Ubuntu one.

What to do? I would love to be able to extract data from Ubuntu.

PS - If recovering data is not possible then can I at least format it to get the space back so I can use the hard disk as an external HDD?

Answer (score 0):

If you boot from a live USB and use 'Try Ubuntu' you should be able to read the partitions and extract the data to a memory stick.

Answer (score 0):

To save your data boot your machine with

[Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) (or USB).

To manage with partitions from Ubuntu use [Gparted](http://gparted.org/) which is also include in Ubuntu as well as in Live CD (or many others linux distributions). You can also boot up with

[Gparted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)

To delete or resize partitions from Windows you can use

[Partition Wizard Mini Tool Home](http://download.cnet.com/Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html?part=dl-6285158&subj=dl&tag=button)

To just copy your data from Linux partitions under Windows use

[ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)